# VBA - Excel + Word integration - Code looping for no reason

Tags: excel, vba, loops, ms-word, paste

I'm creating an Excel document that, among other things, copies a few arrays of data into a Word file.

Everything is working absolutely fine except that, when it pastes the selection I'm interested in, it pastes it infinitely until I intervene by taking down Word via Task Manager.

There is no reason, as far as I can see, for it to loop. So I'm pretty clueless of what to do next, and I was hoping you guys would shed a light into what I'm doing wrong. The concept is as follows:

```
Sub TestA() 
     'Word objects.
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application 
    Dim wdDoc As Word.Document 
    Dim wdbmRange As Word.Range 

     'Excel objects.
    Dim wbBook As Workbook 
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet 
    Dim rnReport As Range 

     'Opening app and document
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application 
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("C:\Users\RCO1\Desktop\Teste VBA\2. Conceptual Testing\Export\XLWDTST.docx") 
    Set wdbmRange = wdDoc.Bookmarks("TableInsertion").Range 

     'Selecting array
    Sheets("ExportMe").Select 
    Range("A1").Select 
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select 
    Selection.Copy 

     'Pasting data
    With wdbmRange 
        .PasteSpecial '<------- it simply goes back up to the beginning of the code at this point
        CutCopyMode = False 
    End With 

     'Closing and saving
    wdDoc.Save 
    wdDoc.Close 
    wdApp.Quit 

    Set wdApp = Nothing 
    Set wdDoc = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Just note that I can't simply transform this array into a table so to speak for formatting reasons.

Comment: Rather than ending the Word process you might try pressing Ctrl+Break on the keyboard while in the VBA environment (Excel) where the code is running.

Comment: Has nothing to do with your problem, but you need to change the order of Set ... = Nothing at the end of the code. Always release objects in the REVERSE order they were instantiated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you use PasteSpecial instead of Paste? If you use F8 to "step" through the code, does it jump? To which line? In 20 years of VBA programming I've never heard of anything like this...

Comment: Hey, Cindy. Thanks for replying. I ended it in .PasteSpecial as one of my failed attempts to solve the issue, and it hasn't. By using F8, it reaches the line where I have it paste the selection, and it goes back to "Sub TestA()" when I press it again.

However, I found the solution by simply entering this:

Sheets("General Exhibit Model BRL").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Copy
.Bookmarks("TableInsertion").Range.PasteExcelTable 0, 0, 0

So no big deal anymore. Thanks a lot, anyway :)

Comment: Glad the problem is solved. Since it's so "odd" I think it would be important that the Question and your solution are saved so that others can find it. Would you mind taking a moment to summarize your findings in an "Answer", including the working code? You can then click the "Answer" checkmark next to it (you're allowed to answer your own question on SO).

Comment: Good call, I'll do that. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

After placing a few inquiries, I have been given the following simple, yet very effective, piece of code:

```
Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Filepath = Sheets("Proposal Generator").Range("I9")
Set wdDoc = Word.Documents.Open(Filepath)

with wdDoc

            Sheets("Shhet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Copy
            .Bookmarks("TableInsertion").Range.PasteExcelTable 0, 0, 0

.SaveAs (TxtSaveFolder.Text & "\" & TxtFileName.Text)

End With
```

I hope this works for anyone who's trying to export tables.